# How to freeze one filter in a layer while keeping other filters trainable?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, pytorch

Suppose that the weight matrix for one layer is [32,64,4,2]. Is it possible to freeze its first filter while keeping the other 31 filters trainable?

I've tried to set requires_grad, however this parameter is for the whole layer.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but not as straightforward as you would think. What `nn.Conv2d` effectively does is it initializes and owns the weight (and bias, if applicable) parameters and then in `forward` it just dispatches to [`functional.conv2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#torch.nn.functional.conv2d).

In order to achieve your goal, you will need to create a class which holds the frozen filter as a [buffer](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#torch.nn.Module.register_buffer) (non-parameter) and the 31 remaining filters as a [parameter](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#torch.nn.Module.register_parameter). Then, in forward, it will just concatenate the buffer and the parameter to obtain a 32-channel filter and dispatch to `functional.conv2d`.